# list of attributes necessary to learn when learning a new noun in German

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, genitive

What are all the attributes necessary to remember, when learning a new noun in German?

Here is my idea of it:

1. its grammatical gender
2. whether it is an adjectival noun or not
3. its plural form
4. ending in the genitive case

**Questions:**

i) Is that correct?

ii) Are there even more attributes to learn?

iii) What are some rules how to deal with / recognize the ending in the attribute 4) ?

**Notes:**
a) Attribute 1) is sometimes not necessary, especially if the noun ends with eg. -schaft, -ung, - keit etc, but in general it is necessary to learn

b) Attribute 4) I am not sure about. In my paper Czech-German dictionary there is written every noun in the form: die Scheibe (~, n); or der Sack ((e)s, ~mit Umlaut+e), so I am guessing that the elements in those brackets are: the genitive ending and the plural form, right?

Thank you.

Comment: die Scheibe (~, n), der Scheibe, die Scheiben. So, yes you are right. But you need to know which form of article to use.

Comment: BTW: what do you mean by adjectival noun. Whether it can be connected with some other noun to form a compound. That would be every noun, I guess.

Comment: Why do you think that learning the grammatical gender is sometimes optional? I'd rather say that is the most important one. Maybe because you had in most of your examples `die`? Well, der Holzschaft... from Schaft. Otherwise: -ung is made up from verbs, so it seems legit https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ung.

Comment: @mic: Presumably, rather a "substantiviertes Adjektiv", because that implies a different declination. OP, please clarify.

Comment: Can't readers be expected to google terms that they don't know? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Nouns/Adjectival_Nouns https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/adjectives-as-nouns/

Comment: Hello. I have already posted a comment below about the adjectival nouns explaining why they are such a nightmare for a student of German.

Comment: Another important feature is weak declension (for masculine nouns, and "das Herz"), as this also will affect the endings for Dative and Accusative: http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/Texte/Flexionskl.html
There are two inflection classes listed here that belong in that category: -en, -en, as well as -ens, -en. E.g. der Affe, des Affen; der Name, des Namens. With more experience it is usually quite easy to identify these nouns beyond the common, seemingly arbitrary ones (such as "Name"). They are usually (often foreign) words for animate beings or people.

Answer (score 1):

I never before have heard the term *"adjectival noun"*. Whatever it mights be, you don't need it when you learn German nouns.

You missed the most important item on your list:

- meaning

Some words have just grammatical functions but no meaning (like *"ein"*, *"und"*, *"wo"* and many others), but nouns always have a meaning. This is why we put nouns into almost all sentences. And with meaning I do not mean *"translation in my native language"*, because every language has nouns with meanings that you will not find in some other languages. It is really hard to express the meaning of the english word *"mind"* in German, on the other hand you will see, that it is difficult to understand the meaning of the German word *"Gemütlichkeit"* when you speak any other language.

One other very important property is

- usage

Do not learn just words! Learn sentences! And learn how to build new sentences.

Comment: I feel this answer is well-intended and contains some good advice, but doesn't really answer tge question. I agree the OP could have made it more explicit, but the question is quite specifically about what aspects to memorize *in order to integrate a noun grammatically correctly into a sentence*. As for the "adjectival noun", I suspect it's supposed to refer to "substantivierte Adjektive", in which case it might be relevant, but I hope the OP will still come back to clarify.

Comment: An adjectival noun is a horrible experience for a student of the German language. Let's think of two nouns: "Hund" and "Gefangener". Here are two sentences for each of them: 1) Der Hund ist schön. 2) Ein Hund ist schön. 3) Der Gefangene ist dumm. 4) Ein Gefangener ist dumm. In the 1) and 2) sentence the word "Hund" has the same ending. In the 3) and 4) sentence the word "Gefangene" has different ending. There is the "r" in addition in the sentence 4). An adjectival noun changes its ending depending to whether there is a definite / indefinite article in front of it.

Comment: With respect to inflection, an adjectival noun does not behave differently from an ordinary adjective.

Comment: @RHa: That may be true, but it's beside the point; it behaves differently from an ordinary *noun*.

Comment: The fact that one also learns the meaning of the word apart from its morphological features is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @Nico: Yes, but the question was not about *non-obvious* attributes, but about *necessary* attributes. And I think, we both agree, that meaning is a necessary attribute. So, it has to be mentioned.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast As you like...